# EMV Issuer Public Key exponent missing, but needed

Tags: emv

i am trying to implement the retrieval of EMV Issuer's Public key according to the specification EMV4.3 Book2. I have been able to decrypt the issuer's public key certificate.

I need to concatenate the Certificate Format through Issuer Public Key + Issuer Public Key Remainder (if present) and finally the Issuer Public key Exponent.

I tried reading the Issuer Public Key Exponent from the Application Data and could not find it. In my recovered data decrypted from the Public Key certificate i can see the length of the exponent=1.

When i check this site

> *https://www.eftlab.co.uk/index.php/site-map/knowledge-base/243-ca-public-keys*

I can see e.g. VISA with Issuer's RID, RID Index, Exponent, Modulus, Key length etc.

Does that mean, each terminal should have the modulus, RID, Index and also the Exponent?. If yes where is it in the specification?.

Can anyone tell me where i need to get the exponent from. I feel like i am missing something from the Specification.

Thanks 
Derick

Comment: Can you update your question from SELECT till final READ RECORD with sensitive data masked ? Also the steps you are trying as a part of ODA. Are you able to see header 6A and trailer BC once you open the Issuer PK certificate ?

Comment: AFAIK issuer pk exponent should be in tag `0x9F32`. You might find sources of [javaemvreader](https://github.com/sasc999/javaemvreader) very useful.

Comment: Hey Guys, i was actually going through all the commands to make a log to show you guys and i actually found my error. I had a do-while loop to read all the records as specified in the AFL, but unfortunately i wrote the code and my break condition did not permit me to always read the end record of each Record specified in the AFL. Thanks to your question @adarsh i had to go through my code again. Thanks. So problem was actually the  Public Key Remainder and Exponent which were actually found in the Records i was not reading. So now i have them and my Hash code corresponds now.

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to it will be to download Contact specification Book 2 ( Security and Key Management) and read sections 5 and 6 with utmost attention. You need to show what you have done so far for us to understand what you are missing.

Yes terminal need to store the CA PK with Index for all the RID it supports. Most of them you can find in the link you showed, but better to get it from the CAs itself.

Answer (score 0):

I found my error. I missed some important records due to a bug in my code. So i was not reading the records which contain the issuer public key remainder and Exponent. So concatenating as in EMV book 2 Chapter 5.3 point 5, was not complete as i did not have the Public Key Remainder and exponent. So calculating the SHA1 digest always gave me a wrong result.

Answer (score -1):

I have released an EMV payment framework (https://github.com/vicente-da-silva/dcemv), what you need is implemented in the VerifySAD.cs file of the DCEMV_EMVProtocol project.